# Trying to make unity only continue the script when a button is pressed

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unity-game-engine

I'm creating a turn based battle, and as of now the text at the bottom of the screen moves at a set time using WaitForSeconds, however I would rather it only move forward when the F key is pressed.

Im pretty sure I'd have to use GetKeyPressed, but I cant think of a way to implement it. Would I use some sort of loop to just wait for every single point I need the f key to be pressed? Do I create a function that handles it?

The code:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;
using UnityEditor;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using TMPro;

public enum BattleState { START, PLAYERTURN, ENEMYTURN, WON, LOST }

public class BattleSystem : MonoBehaviour
{

    public GameObject playerPrefab;
    public GameObject enemyPrefab;

    public Transform playerBattleStation;
    public Transform enemyBattleStation;

    public TMP_Text dialogueText;

    Unit playerUnit;
    Unit enemyUnit;

    public BattleHUDScript playerHUD;
    public BattleHUDScript enemyHUD;

    

    

    
    
    public BattleState state;
    void Start()
    {
        state = BattleState.START;
        StartCoroutine(SetupBattle());
    }

    private IEnumerator SetupBattle()
    {
        GameObject playerGO = Instantiate(playerPrefab, playerBattleStation);
        playerUnit = playerGO.GetComponent<Unit>();


        GameObject enemyGO = Instantiate(enemyPrefab, enemyBattleStation);
        enemyUnit = enemyGO.GetComponent<Unit>();

        enemyUnit.basedamage = PlayerPrefs.GetInt("playerMaxDamage");
        enemyUnit.baseHP = PlayerPrefs.GetInt("playerMaxHP");
        enemyUnit.baseMP = PlayerPrefs.GetInt("playerMaxMana");
        enemyUnit.basespeed = PlayerPrefs.GetInt("playerMaxSpeed");

        enemyUnit.currHP = enemyUnit.baseHP;
        enemyUnit.currMP = enemyUnit.baseMP;
        enemyUnit.currspeed = enemyUnit.basespeed;
        enemyUnit.currdamage = enemyUnit.basedamage;



        dialogueText.text = enemyUnit.unitName + " Attacked!";

        playerHUD.SetHUD(playerUnit);
        enemyHUD.SetHUD(enemyUnit);

        yield return new WaitForSeconds(2f);

        state = BattleState.PLAYERTURN;

        PlayerTurn();
    }

    private void PlayerTurn()
    {
        dialogueText.text = "Choose an action: ";
    }

    IEnumerator PlayerAttack()
    {
        bool isDead = enemyUnit.TakeDamage(playerUnit.currdamage);

        enemyHUD.SetHP(enemyUnit.currHP);
        dialogueText.text = "The attack hits!";

        yield return new WaitForSeconds(2f);

        if (isDead ) 
        {
            state = BattleState.WON;
            EndBattle();

        }
        else
        {
            state = BattleState.ENEMYTURN;
            StartCoroutine(EnemyTurn());
        }
    }

    IEnumerator EnemyTurn()
    {
        dialogueText.text = enemyUnit.unitName + " attacks!";

        yield return new WaitForSeconds(1f);

        bool isDead = playerUnit.TakeDamage(enemyUnit.currdamage);

        playerHUD.SetHP(playerUnit.currHP);

        yield return new WaitForSeconds(1f);

        if (isDead)
        {
            state = BattleState.LOST;
            EndBattle();
        }
        else
        {
            state = BattleState.PLAYERTURN;
            PlayerTurn();
        }
    }     
    void EndBattle()
    {
       if(state == BattleState.WON) 
        {
           dialogueText.text = "You won the battle!";
        }
       else if (state == BattleState.LOST)
        {
            dialogueText.text = "You were defeated";
        }

    }

    public void OnFightButton()
    {
        if (state != BattleState.PLAYERTURN)
        {
            return;


           
        }
        StartCoroutine(PlayerAttack());
    }


}
```

Comment: Can you show a screenshot? @HGBadger

Comment: If you need F to be pressed. Set a boolean to false. Waituntil the bool is true. Elsewhere on pressing F set bool to be true

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at [CustomYieldInstruction](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/CustomYieldInstruction.html)

You could create a new CustomYieldInstruction that waits until a key is pressed.
It could look something like this:

```
using UnityEngine;

public class WaitForKey : CustomYieldInstruction
{
    private KeyCode _key;
    
    public override bool keepWaiting
    {
        get
        {
            return !Input.GetKey(_key);
        }
    }

    public WaitForKey(KeyCode key)
    {
        _key = key;
    }
}
```

Now to apply this in your IEnumerator method simply type

```
yield return new WaitForKey(KeyCode.F);
```

and the coroutine should halt until the F key is pressed

Comment: Followed this and it worked perfectly! Thanks heaps!

Comment: @HGBadger If this answer is helpful to you, you can mark it so that more people can be helped